# Minimum Password length: Getting error when length conforms to minimum

Tags: windows, password

trying to determine why my machine is enforcing a minimum 15-char password when it appears it's set to 14.  We have a GPO that sets the length to 14, so here's what I see on the machine (should account for everything trying to set the length):

- "minPwdLength" DC domain object property reads "14" in ADSI Edit.
- `dsquery * -filter "(minPwdAge=*)" -attr distinguishedName minPwdLength` returns 14
- `net accounts` returns "14"

Yet when I try to set a password to that length, I get "The password does not meet the password policy requirements..." (using "net user" cmd) or "0x80070c5" (using "dsa.msc"; means same thing).  I need to set it to at least 15 chars to avoid the error.

Comment: It's quite possible the setting doesn't actually mean "minimum length" but "password needs to be longer than" -- why is this a problem? If you want the minimum to be 14, with the observed behavior you should just be able to set it to 13.

Comment: Length is not the only thing that applies to password policies. Have you checked things like complexity, minimum age (aka password changed too recently to change again), and previous passwords remembered?

Comment: Thx @pzkpfw, I'm 1st trying to understand why the rule interrogation doesn't match the value, in case there are other issues we need to address site wide. It's a problem because it's not behaving as expected and we need to understand how it actually works. Like is there some Windows pwd standard that says "always add 1 to the value you specify" (sounds kinda silly)? Users have to know exactly what they're requirements are.

Comment: Thx @RyanBolger, I realize, but it's the length; as soon as I add 1 char it works fine.